# cross domain window opener button click

Tags: javascript, web, cross-domain

Can I call onclick of any element of opener window from child window running on different domains

I have a web page in

> http://mydomain.com/app/main.html

it opens a page on an other domain

> http://domain2.com/app3/addandsave.html

now on main.html page (opener) I want to click button from addandsave.html (child window) can i do it, I can't update pages in mydomain

Answer (score 1):

Standard security restrictions in browsers prevent the accessing of the DOM of a page loaded from a different origin, so in general: No.

With the cooperation of the other site, you can pass messages using `postMessage` and respond to them using JS loaded by the other site.

With the cooperation of the user, you can write a browser extensions that isn't subject to the usual security restrictions.